# Applying conditions on a function

Tags: functions

Suppose there's a function $f(x)$ defined over the whole interval $[a,b]$ (assume f(x) to be real).
What condition should I put on $f(x)$ so that it satisfies the following:

$\displaystyle{
min f' ≤ \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} ≤ max f'
}$

where $min f'$ and $max f'$ are respectively the minimum and maximum values of $f'$ over the interval $[a,b]$.

My intuition says two things:

- $f'$ be continuous over $[a,b]$, or,
- $f''$ be defined over entire interval $[a,b]$.

However I am not really able to justify any of them (or disprove them).
What the conditions could be?

Comment: $f'$ being continuous is sufficient condition.

Comment: @Pratik how can I show it rigorously?

Comment: If $f'$ is continuous then it takes minimum value and maximum vaue in compact [(closed and bounded)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) domain $[0,1]$ then use Mean Value thrm as done by @John in his answer

Comment: @Pratik what is a compact subset $[1,0]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the Mean Value Theorem.

Since $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous. Therefore, there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

But $min f'\le f'(c)\le max f'$.

Comment: that the inequality follows immediately from mean value theorem is understandable but first we need to be sure that f' is Bounded in [a,b], how that follows is the bugging part for me.

Comment: A continuous function on a compact set is bounded because of the Extreme Value Theorem.